# lcm of 3 numbers--by a recursive formula?

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\lcm}{lcm}
\DeclareMathOperator{\gcd}{gcd}
$$

I have to find the $\lcm(39,102,75)$. I am thinking of using a recursive formula like this:

$$
\lcm(39,102,75) = \frac{\lcm(39 \times 102) \times 75}{\gcd(39,102,75)}
= \frac{\frac{39 \times 102 \times 75}{\gcd(39, 102)}}{\gcd(39,102,75)}
$$

I get a result of 33150 which indeed is the $\lcm(39,102,75)$ by inspection. This seems to be similar to what [A method to find out LCM(least common multiple) for a list of numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/975142/a-method-to-find-out-lcmleast-common-multiple-for-a-list-of-numbers) is doing, but I have expanded it fully to make sense of it. Is this right?

Comment: Can you show how you expanded it from that formula? If I plug in $lcm (2, 3, 2) = 6$, it is not equal to $ lcm(2 \times 3) \times 2 / \gcd(2, 3, 2) = 12$.

Comment: Is there some reason not to use $\operatorname{lcm}(a, b, c)=\operatorname{lcm}(\operatorname{lcm}(a, b), c)$?

Comment: @RobertShore That's part of what I'm asking. The linked question states that formula, and so I'm wondering how OP arrived at their equation.

Comment: I think $lcm(lcm(a,b),c)$ is the same as $\frac{lcm(a,b) \times c}{gcd(a,b,c)}$?

Comment: I added [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/975142) to the question you linked to that might be helpful here, too.